# Is there a way to include a legend bar into a geotiff image file?

Tags: python, geotiff

I need to use an API that only allows sending a RGB Geotiff image to be visualized over a map to an specif location. However, it is really important that this image has a legend bar included showing what value is related to an specific color, as shown here https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11286381/36511755-b58e6cc8-171c-11e8-9385-e90c3795be14.png.

I did not find any way to overlay or include a legend without lose its georeferencing information.

Comment: If the image data exists in a standard image file format during its construction, you could use the PIL (Python Imaging Library) to add the legend bar to it prior to it's conversion to geotiff format.

Comment: Thanks @martineau. It did work.